# Is there a way to read information from a saved file to check if there is an already exisiting doctorID saved?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

So I am trying to create a Medical Clinic System Management program for a school project. This is my first project using NetBeans to create a GUI and unfortunately, my class spent about two weeks on the topic so I am not as well versed in this as I wish I was. So please don't be too harsh on my code. When I create a doctor object, the data gets saved to a file. When I go back and attempt to create another doctor with the same ID, my boolean isKeyPresent does not catch it because (I'm assuming) my doctor map is not associated with any of the doctors created in the save file. How can I fix this, so my system does not make a doctor if the ID is already in use?

```
private void btnAddDoctorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        
        try {
            
            String id = txtDocID.getText();
            String name = txtDocName.getText();
            String specialty = txtSpecialty.getText();
        
            boolean isKeyPresent = administrative.doctors.containsKey(id);
            if(isKeyPresent) {
            
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Doctor ID Already Exists");
            }
            else {
            
                addDoctor(name, specialty, id);
                String s = name + ",";
                s += specialty + ",";
                s += id;
            
                FileWriter w = new FileWriter(fileLocation);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(w);
                writer.write(s);
                writer.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Doctor Added");
            }        
            txtDocID.setText("");
            txtDocName.setText("");
            txtSpecialty.setText("");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you learned about databases?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I looked in my textbook and quickly looked through it, nothing there seems familiar or is anything that was taught to me.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Is there anything specific I can look up that might be of use to me? My book goes through some different options but my inexperience with them makes me unsure of what route to take.

Comment: There is obviously something wrong with the administrative.doctors.containsKey(id) method. **It should have picked up on a duplicate ID** and then focus should immediately fall back onto the ID textfield (`txtDocID.requestFocus()`) and exit the event. I would think that when a unique instance of Doctor is created (or any change to a Doctor instance is made), it should then be applied to the collection and the collection immediately saved to file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd recommend converting the doctor id in the `txtDocID` field to lowercase (`String#toLowerCase`) when you access it, as that'd prevent the user from inputting a duplicate ID just with different casing.

I'm not sure what your `addDoctor` method does, I'm guessing it just adds it to the GUI. It'd be useful if you included the code for that. If that's the case, then you are correct in assuming the problem is that the `administrative.doctors` Map is not linked to your save file.

One way you could fix this is by also adding the doctor to the `administrative.doctors` Map after saving it to the save file.

However, I'd advice that you make a separate class for handling the saving and storage of doctors. This way you could simply call something like `DoctorManager#saveDoctor` and it would write to the file and save to the internal Map. It'd also be worth encapsulating the Map.

Finally, regarding the comment on a database, it sounds like you haven't been taught about them yet and its probably not worth the hassle for your use-case anyway. Abstracting your code to use a separate class for managing storage of doctors is likely ideal.